# Django - Create random dummy data for testing that doesn't break the test suite

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I'm trying to think of a way to create random test data of a certain model type for running `python manage.py test`. So for example if I have a model `Post` like below.

`model.py`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator")
    body = models.CharField(max_length=POST_MAX_LEN, validators=[MinLengthValidator(POST_MIN_LEN)])
```

some sort of library that'll generate this with random `body`, random `creator` from user table would be nice. I tried [factory boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/orms.html), but when the test DB rolls back the DB after a test function it seems to rollback factory boy created dummy data as well even if it's declared in `setUpTestData` function. This rollback process causes a constraint error since the original data no longer exists. **What's a good library or way to create dummy data for Django testing that doesn't break the test suite?**

`dummy_factory.py`

```
from factory.django import DjangoModelFactory

class PostFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Post

    creator = factory.Iterator(User.objects.all())
    body = factory.Faker('text')
```

**Note:**
Another option is to just create a function let's say `make_dummy_post` that uses `Post.objects.create()` and randomly samples a `User` and uses factory boy generators to generate `body`, but I feel like there's a better way to do it than this.

Answer (score 1):

First `pip install model_bakery`, then:

```
from model_bakery import baker


# app_name.model_name
model_obj = baker.make("post.Post")
```

Here is the [**[docs]**](https://model-bakery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more info.

Comment: what are the key differences between `model_bakery` and `factory boy`? Seems like `factory boy` is meant more for creating dummy data on your DB for testing API calls, while `model_bakery` according to their docs is for testing. Behind the hood, what makes one for testing and one for dummy data creation?

Comment: Because people usually create data for testing instead of production, they are kinda same, but i found `model_bakery` is easier to use.

Comment: my biggest concern is running into the issue I had with `factory boy`, which is that in initial data gen. Any data created by `factory boy` got rolled back at the end of a test function.